# glm::unProject giving half expected values

Tags: c++, opengl, projection, glm-math

I'm having an issue with glm::unProject. I'm trying to convert cursor position in my QGLWidget to world coordinates. However, the coordinates coming out of unProject are half what they should be.

I've drawn a few shapes at specific coordinates and if I mouse over them the coordinates are half what they were drawn at.

[image: cubes]

In the picture above the left cube is at the origin and the right is at `(1, 0, 0)` but unProject tells me it's at `(.5, 0, 0)`

If I draw another cube at where my mouse is currently it will render halfway between my mouse and the origin.

```
glm::unProject(glm::vec3(mouse_x, window_height - mouse_y, mouse_z),
               glm::lookAt(camera_position, camera_look_at, camera_up),
               glm::perspective(fov, window_width / window_height, near, far),
               glm::vec4(0, 0, window_width, window_height));
```

If I double the result from the above call then my result coordinates are ok. However, I don't think that's the right solution I suspect there is something wrong with my parameters.

Comment: Where does your `mouse_z` come from?

Comment: It's being calculated using glm::project on the origin using all the same parameters we're using for unProject.

Comment: In the general case, just using that as the z coordinate will not work, since the plane `z=mouse_z` in window space does not neccesarily contain your two cube centers. However, in your specific case, your camera might be placed in such a way that it matches, so I don't think that that is the issue here.